# for loop doesn't work in Django template (inside of table tag)

Tags: django, django-models, html-table, django-templates

i'm trying to create a table inside of my **html template**,
but when i write `<td>{{project.title}}</td>` it doesn't work!
actually when i use **{{x}}** i have no output!
i don't really know what's wrong inside of my template...

html template:

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}


{% block content %}
 
<h1>Projects</h1>


<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Project</th>
        <th>Votes</th>
        <th>Ratio</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    {% for project in Projects %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{project.id}}</td>
        <td>{{project.title}}</td>
        <td>{{project.vote_total}}</td>
        <td>{{project.vote_ratio}}</td>
        <td>{{project.created}}</td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'project' project.id %}">View</a></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>

{% endblock content %}
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
import uuid

from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE 
# Create your models here.


class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    descripeion = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    demo_link = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    source_link = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True, blank=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True)
    vote_total = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    vote_ratio = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, 
    editable=False)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title    

class Review(models.Model):
    VOTE_TYPE = (
        ('up', 'Up Vote'),
        ('down', 'Down Vote')
    )
    # owner =
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=VOTE_TYPE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, 
    editable=False)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.value

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, 
    editable=False)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Project


projectsList = [
    {
        'id':'1',
        'title':'Ecommerce Website',
        'description':'Fully functional ecommerce website'
    },
    {
        'id':'2',
        'title':'Portfolio Website',
        'description':'This was a project where i built out my 
         portfolio'
    },
    {
        'id':'3',
        'title':'Social network',
        'description':'owesome open source project i am still 
         working'
    },
]


def projects(request):
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    context = {'projects': projects}
    return render(request, 'projects/projects.html',context)

def project(request, pk):
    projectObj = Project.objects.get(id=pk)
    return render(request, 'projects/single-project.html', 
                                  {'project': projectObj})
```

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Project, Review, Tag

admin.site.register(Project)
admin.site.register(Review)
admin.site.register(Tag)
```

[the files and folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBzbD.png)

**Anyone know what I am doing wrong here?**

Comment: Can you share the view where you render this template?

Comment: As Willem says, we need to see the view so we can see what you're providing in the context for the template. Perhaps `Projects` isn't in the context.

Comment: @markwalker_ please check out my question again, i edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are passing projects in context processor with small case "p" , Make it as

```
{% for project in projects %}
```

in your template.